# Seed Dump with Comfortable Mexican Sofa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding, comfortable-mexican-sofa

In previous apps when the same database data has been required by everyone we've used `seed_dumper` & `rake db:seed:dump` to populate the seeds file and then `rake db:seed`.

For this app, using the Comfortable Mexican Sofa CMS gem and the fortress plugin it would be nice to do the same. Only seed_dumper only dumps the users - nothing else.

`seed_dump` (the 'parent' gem) gives the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `cms_manageable' for Comfy::Cms::Page(Table doesn't exist):Class
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
/path to my app/app/models/comfy/cms/page.rb:9:in `<class:Page>'
```

Any ideas or alternate methods would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Have a feeling you're using cms from the master branch and not the released version. Might be causing some issues.

Comment: Just using whatever you get with gem install. We've settled for including the SQLite development database in the git tracking for the time being.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/obfusk/active-dump ?

Comment: Just given it a go now, still no joy I'm afraid. `undefined local variable or method `cms_manageable'`. Adding the SQLite db file to the git tracking has helped. When the time comes though this: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Working-with-CMS-fixtures might be the method used. 

I think the issue is that the cms_tables aren't all linked to models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now using only `gem 'seed_dump'` (not `seed_dumper`), running the command `bundle exec rake db:seed:dump` works for exporting seed data.